# c# open an windows form app another

Tags: c#, winforms

there I try to open an wfapp from another and when I run the code :An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll 
There is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Panel panel1 = new Panel();


        Process p = Process.Start("ap.exe");
        //Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `SetParent`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because, your code is not able to find `ap.exe`, please give the correct path.

I was able to reproduce the same error, when the file name given to `Process` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the Indian Programmer is correct.

Your path should be something like:

`"C:\Users\YourUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Yourapp\Yourapp\bin\debug\ap.exe"`

Assuming you are using VS 2013 and debugging it.

If you use just "ap.exe" then it should be present in debug folder or it won't find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i moved the exe to the project folder and it works